# Eventos del Mouse

Tags: java-swing, netbeans-8.2

Quiero abrir un Frame desde otro pasando el Mouse encima de un jbutton y al quitar el cursor encima del jbutton cerrar el frame.

Lo primero ya lo he logrado con esto:

```
private void btnAboutMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    About f = new About();
    /*f.setVisible(true);*/
    f.show();

}
```

Cualquier metodo anterior me es funcional.
Solo que al quitar el cursor del control no se que evento debo utilizar para que el Frame se cierra, he intentado con el evento Exited y FocusLost, pero no me cierra el frame lo cierra hasta que doy clic en algun otro control del Frame principal.
Alguna sugerencia?

Estos son los eventos que he intentado:

```
    private void btnAboutMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
     About f = new About();
    /*f.setVisible(false);*/ 
    f.dispose();
}                                    

private void btnAboutFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                   
    About f = new About();
     /*f.setVisible(false);*/ 
    f.dispose();             
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar

DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo una clase que impementa lo que quieres

```
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class Ventana extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

 JButton boton;
 JFrame ventanaHija;

  public Ventana() {
      setBounds(0,0,500,500);
      setLayout(null);
      boton=new JButton("boton");
      boton.setBounds(100,100,100,30);
      boton.addMouseListener(this); //aca ponemos a la escucha el boton.
      add(boton);
      setVisible(true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  }

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {//aqui se crea y abre la ventana
    ventanaHija=new JFrame();
    ventanaHija.setBounds(500,0,200,200);
    ventanaHija.setVisible(true);


}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { //aca se cierra
    ventanaHija.dispose();


}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Julio enrique godoy
Me ayudo mucho tu propuesta.